# PHP Gallery not working

Tags: php, image-gallery

I'm creating PHP gallery for my website. It will be displayed inside iFrame inside of normal HTML page.

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table><tr>
<?php
define('Photo_dir','img');
define('Columns',2);
$x=0;
$y=0;
$results = scandir(Photo_dir);
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;
    if (is_dir(Photo_dir.'/'.$result))
    {
        if($y > 2)
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $y=0;
            $x=&x+1;
        }
        echo "<td><img src='image.php?photo=".Photo_dir."/".$result."/1.jpg'/></td>";
        echo "kod w html";
    }
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason it is not working. Browser doesn't even see `<table>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a live example to demonstrate the problem? You should also have `<head><title></title></head>` prior to opening the body for validity.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse adding '<head><title></title></head>' doesn't change anything. Live demo version is here: marcinm.jcom.pl/gallery.php. I have updated code in question to actual version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in there, on the line where you increment the variable `$x` you're trying to increment `&x`. It should be:

```
$x = $x +1;
```

Another easy way to increment variables by one is to do:

```
$x++;
```

As for the reason you're not seeing any output at all, it looks like it's a 500 error (that's what Chrome reports anyway), which means the server itself is doing a boo-boo. Check your server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the constants and variables all old the right information, aren't you missing the opening quote:

```
<img src='image.php?photo=".Photo_dir."/".$result."/1.jpg'/>
         ^ that one.
```

Comment: @bartexsz Okay, what error are you getting? Is it entering the loop at all? Are you getting the table output, but the `src` is all wrong?

Comment: I'm not getting anything at all, It's only empty website. As for Opera Dragonfly There are only html and body tags.